# which is correct?, at the interview ... or at interview

Tags: articles, definite-articles

> At interview she was casually dressed with good hygiene and engaged well.

or

> At ***the*** interview she was casually dressed with good hygiene and engaged well.

Comment: ...begs the question...exactly how was the candidate's good hygiene ascertained?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. The second is far more common, but the first one is occasionally used - it would be taken to mean "at interview *stage*". A bit like you can say "at dinner" or "at the dinner".

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary in this specific context to use the definite article because, **from the point of view of the writer**,   the sentence NOT is about some specific situation about some specific interview. It is about the interview stage in some organisation's recruitment process.

The hygienic lady who was interviewed would undoubtedly refer to 'the interview' but for the writer, apparently the person reporting the results of that interview, who has  probably interviewed dozens of applicants, it is a generic description of that part of the process.

The usage is exactly the same as you will find in the medical profession: 'the patient presented with a painful shoulder, on examination a growth was found, in surgery more complications emerged, in convalescence the symptoms abated'.

Answer (score 1):

From the context, it is evident that the sentence is about some specific situation about some specific interview. "Interview" is not an abstract term in this case, so it is necessary to use the definite article. Please view [The definite article](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/)

> Use the to refer to something which has already been mentioned.

Source: (https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/) - EF Education First English Grammar Quide

Comment: Hello, Victor, and welcome to EL&U. Please feel free to take the [Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), or visit our [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see what a good answer should look like.

Comment: The actual question is about the use of articles, and why in certain circumstances we have definite articles or zero articles. Possibly it  wasn't clear the way it was written, but I have edited the Q to make it more clear.

Comment: @Cascabel, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Better...but could I suggest that you include in "block quote" the pertinent part of that link, as links decay over time, and users get annoyed when they have to click to see.   BTW, not my downvote. When you edit I will +1

Comment: @Cascabel, Thank you for the suggestions. I have updated the answer one more time.

Comment: I also added a  "hard" link, but I did not do an attribution. Perhaps you could unleash some google-fu and edit that in? As promised, I +1ed

Comment: @Cascabel, interesting information about Attribution, thanks.But the more full and more correct answer has been added. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Interview** is a countable noun with the plural form being "interviews" (there's no abstract form that I know of).

An article is definitely needed or it would be grammatically incorrect.

If the listener doesn't know what particular interview you're talking about use **At an interview** and if the listener is aware of the context use **At the interview**

Hope that helps.